# Exception in Inserting data into table using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to insert record into table using entity framework. I Know how to do it and i have done but i modified the database by adding a new table "PasswordRecovery" and then i update my .edmx file and then i try to insert the record into that table

```
PasswordRecovery OPasswordRecovery = new PasswordRecovery
                {
                    userId = user.Id,
                    url = token,
                    requestDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    isRecoverd = false
                };
                context.PasswordRecoveries.Add(OPasswordRecovery);
                context.SaveChanges();
```

But the Exception "Invalid object name 'dbo.PasswordRecoveries"

Please help me

Comment: Shouldn't context.PasswordRecoveries be context.PasswordRecovery that is the table you added in DB?

Comment: @Deepshikha Not if you check "Pluralize table name" when generating .edmx
Vicky : Did you regenerate your whole project after updating edmx ? The code seems OK to me...

Comment: Not sure this is related, but once I had to regenerate the .edmx to make EF aware of the new table I created. Update of .edmx did not work. May be worth the try?

Comment: @AlexB Yes I regenerate but the problem remain same.

Comment: Last time I had unsolvable problems with edmx, I deleted the file (not just empty the file, really *delete* it) and recreate it, and it works like a charm... never understand why, but whatever... So, I suggest to do the same, and if it's still doesn't work, post more code to help us to understand where is the problem